# How to Stop back-ground music in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

On one of activity, i am retrieving an webpage using using URL. when you hit that page,it starts playing some sort of music. Problem is that that music keeps playing in backgroud even you exit the app. I want to get rid of it...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mp3);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
        http://runnable.com/Us5yYIzciVFWAAYA/how-to-create-a-new-linked-list-for-c%2B%2B
        actionBar.setTitle(title);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.bg_tabbar );
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(myIcon);
        try{
             webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            final String url = intent.getStringExtra("Link");
            Log.w("URL", url);
            webview.clearCache(true);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
            webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            if(title.equals("Read Quran"))
            {
                webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                webview.setInitialScale(1);
            }
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
           webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.w("URL1", url);
                    webview.clearCache(true); 
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                    try{
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        String custom_message="Error! Please Connect to the Internet!";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , custom_message , duration);
                        toast.show();

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , e.toString() , duration);
                        toast.show();
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    finish();
                }

            });

            Log.w("Web2","OK");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Web View Exception",e.toString());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
```

URL is in other file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load blanc page when your Activity destroyed:

```
onDestroy(){
    webView.setWebViewClient(null);
    webView.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");

    super.onDestroy();
}
```